# The groupoid cardinality of $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector spaces $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, \bigl(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} q^n-q^i\bigr)^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, category-theory, closed-form, q-analogs

Let $q > 1$. What can we say about the value of
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \, \bigl(\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} q^n-q^i\bigr)^{-1} ~~?$$
The series clearly converges. Is there a closed form or something like that?

Background: If $q$ is a prime power, then this is the [cardinality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid+cardinality) of the groupoid of finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_q$-vector spaces. Since $\mathbb{F}_1$-vector spaces are pointed sets and the cardinality of the category of finite pointed sets is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = e$, the above series may be seen as a $q$-analog of $e$.

Comment: @Normal Human: Thank you for editing.

Comment: What on Earth is a $\Bbb F_1$-vector space? So far, I've only ever seen "field with one element" occur as either a joke or a reference to some kind of fuzzy philosophy. I see no relation with $\Bbb F_q$-vector spaces.

Comment: It is a pointed set, as mentioned in my post. The field with 1 element is no joke at all. You can read https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0069 to get started.

Comment: And in case you know German: https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/article.php?sid=1912

Comment: Yes you did say it was a pointed set. I was more hoping for a generalised definition to vector space that reduces to a pointed set in the instance of ‘$\Bbb F_1$’. It seems the German article simplify defined $\Bbb F_1$-vector spaces as pointed sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We start with
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(q^n-q^i\right)\right)^{-1}}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(q^n-q^i\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{-n^2}}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{i-n}\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{-n^2}}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{-i-1}\right)}\tag{$i\to n-1-i$}\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{-n^2}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-q^{-i}\right)}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Now it's time for some beautiful math from chapter 7, *Identities of the Rogers-Ramanujan Type* from *[The Theory of Partitions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-1/issue-1/Review-George-E-Andrews-The-theory-of-partitions/bams/1183542336.full)* by G. E. Andrews.

We consider a function $F(x)$ analytic in $x$ at $0$, $F(0)=1$ such that the linear, second-order $q$-difference equation
\begin{align*}
F(x)=F(xq)+xqF(xq^2)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
holds. We set
\begin{align*}
c(x,q):=\frac{F(x)}{F(xq)}
\end{align*}
from which
\begin{align*}
c(x,q)&=1+\frac{xq}{c(xq,q)}\\
&=1+\frac{xq}{1+\frac{xq^2}{c(xq^2,q)}}\cdots\tag{3}
\end{align*}
follows. If we set
\begin{align*}
F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(q)x^n\tag{4}
\end{align*}
we obtain from (2)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(q)x^n=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(q)(xq)^n+xq\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(q)(xq^2)^n
\end{align*}
and comparing coefficients gives
\begin{align*}
A_n(q)&=q^nA_n(q)+q^{2n-1}A_{n-1}(q)\\
\color{blue}{A_n(q)}&=\frac{q^{2n-1}}{1-q^n}A_{n-1}(q)\\
&=\frac{q^{(2n-1)+(2n-3)}}{\left(1-q^n\right)\left(1-q^{n-1}\right)}A_{n-2}(q)\\
&=\cdots\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{q^{1+3+\cdots+(2n-1)}}{\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-q^i\right)}A_0(q)}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

We obtain from (4) and (5)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n^2}}{\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-q^i\right)}x^n}
\end{align*}
and verbatim from the book:

> Surprisingly $F(1)$ and $F(q)$ may be evaluated in terms of infinite products (as we shall prove later in this chapter), namely,
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F(1)}&=1+\frac{q}{1-q}+\frac{q^4}{(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)}
> +\frac{q^9}{(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)\left(1-q^3\right)}+\cdots\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{5n+1}\right)^{-1}\left(1-q^{5n+4}\right)^{-1}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> and
> \begin{align*}
> F(q)&=1+\frac{q^2}{1-q}+\frac{q^6}{(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)}
> +\frac{q^{12}}{(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)\left(1-q^3\right)}+\cdots\\
> &=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{5n+2}\right)^{-1}\left(1-q^{5n+3}\right)^{-1}
> \end{align*}

We conclude from (1)  and (6)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(q^n-q^i\right)\right)^{-1}
=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{-(5n+1)}\right)^{-1}\left(1-q^{-(5n+4)}\right)^{-1}\qquad\qquad |q|>1}
\end{align*}

---

**Note:** This is just a side-note from the introductory section of chapter 7. S.Ramanujan sent the following beautiful formulas to G. H. Hardy on 16 January 1913:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-4\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-6\pi}}{\vdots}}}}
=\left(\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\right)e^{2\pi/5}\\
1-\frac{e^{-\pi}}{1+\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{1-\frac{e^{-3\pi}}{\vdots}}}
=\left(\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)e^{\pi/5}\\
\end{align*}
Note that these continued fraction theorems are evaluations of (3), namely
\begin{align*}
c\left(1,e^{-2\pi}\right)\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad c\left(1,-e^{-\pi}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! I assume this cannot be simplified any further, then? I have approximated the result for some numbers $q$ (see below). Are there "closed formulas"?$$\begin{array}{l|l}2 & 2.1726687508496636 \\  3 & 1.52092240589268 \\ 4 & 1.3388944006904473 \\ 5 & 1.25208400538496 \\ 6 & 1.2009525039994555 \\ 7 & 1.1671627280124328  \end{array}$$

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: You're welcome! My pleasure! :-) I'm not aware of any other simplifications.

Comment: Alright. And I just noticed that (1) is the equation in the answer by Sangchul Lee.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, it was Sangchul Lee's kind and instructive reply that set me on the right path. He is a formidable source of inspiration. :-)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Many thanks for granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 12):

The function you asked is related to the function

$$ G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(1-x)\cdots(1-x^n)} $$

appearing in [*Rogers-Ramanujan identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_identities) by

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bigg( \prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (q^n-q^i) \Bigg)^{-1} = G(1/q). $$

I learned that this has been studied in combinatorics since the coefficients in the series expansion admit combinatorial interpretation in terms of partitions (see [OEIS A003114](https://oeis.org/A003114) for the coefficient list of $G(x)$), but I am not sure if this will help you and I also do not know its number-theoretic properties.